# ajax, syntax error: unexpected token A in json at position 0

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, syntax

I make an ajax request, and returned in json form, but it gives me "syntax error: unexpected token A  in json at position 0" every time, I will post my ajax code below, thanks.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/report/get-judge-optionals", type:'GET', dataType:'json', cache:true,
        data: {
            inputRole: $(this).attr('data-role'),
            court: selected.data("court"),
            judge: selected.data('value'),
            master: fields.master,
            report_id: fields.report_id
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {},
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(errorThrown);},
        complete: function(jqXHR,status) {}
    });
```

what is returned from controller function is

```
Zend\View\Model\JsonModel Object
(
[captureTo:protected] => 
[jsonpCallback:protected] => 
[terminate:protected] => 1
[children:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[options:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[template:protected] => 
[variables:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [proc_cat_id] => 4
                [0] => 4
                [proc_cat_name] => Class Action (343)
                [1] => Class Action
                [dec_count] => 343
                [2] => 343
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [proc_cat_id] => 2
                [0] => 2
                [proc_cat_name] => Action (323)
                [1] => Action
                [dec_count] => 323
                [2] => 323
            )


    )

[append:protected] => 
)
```

Thanks again

Comment: That error means that what you're returning in the response is not valid JSON. Check the response in the network tab of the console

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your quick reply, the resonse is  {"0":{"proc_cat_id":"4","0":"4","proc_cat_name":"Class Action (343)","1":"Class Action","dec_count":"343","2":"343"},"1":{"proc_cat_id":"2","0":"2","proc_cat_name":"Action (323)","1":"Action","dec_count":"323","2":"323"}}

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the JSON response {"0" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like the response you're getting is a print_r output, you should use

```
echo json_encode($object)
```

also, if the above does not work, I would look for UTF8-BOM characters outputted from you server scripts

Comment: I just realized how stupid I am, I do have a print_r in my controller, I totally forgot about that. thank you!

Comment: @FJShen an upvote (useful) and accept will be appreciated by all SO users, as well as encourage itaynoy to further contribute here.