# Error in console output for json_encode to display the result in console?

Tags: php, json, ajax

FYI, I am working on localhost with wampserver, using PHP and AJAX, trying to display the JSON data rows (which are around 1526). and the problem is i am not able to display the rows which are based on the search conditions.

Output of `print_r($result_array);` in console output as below. here in below pic don't worry for console error this error is becoz of PHP array used in parsing JSON. This output i used to test weather my server PHP file is working correctly or not but it is working correctly.

[image]

After that i checked my encoding function, for which output of `echo json_encode($result_array);` i am getting red console error for some search condition and in other search condition i am able to display results correctly.
For example, below two images

[image]

[image]

**I am not able to figure out what is happening to my code.**

File `search.php`

```
<?php 

        // send a JSON encoded array to client

        include('connection.php');

        $sqlFlag = 0;

        function queryDelimiter(){
            global $sqlFlag;
            if ($sqlFlag == 0){
                $sqlFlag = 1;
                return ' WHERE ';
            }else{
                return ' AND ';
            }
        }

        $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info";

        if(isset($_POST['lead_status']) and strlen(trim($_POST['lead_status'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LeadStatus = '".$_POST['lead_status']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['lead_owner']) and strlen(trim($_POST['lead_owner'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LeadAddedBy = '".$_POST['lead_owner']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['company_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['company_name'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."Company = '".$_POST['company_name']."'";
        }       

        if(isset($_POST['tech_area']) and strlen(trim($_POST['tech_area'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."TechArea = '".$_POST['tech_area']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['firm_size']) and strlen(trim($_POST['firm_size'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."FirmSize = '".$_POST['firm_size']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['firm_type']) and strlen(trim($_POST['firm_type'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."FirmType = '".$_POST['firm_type']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['country_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['country_name'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."Country = '".$_POST['country_name']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['state_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['state_name'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."State = '".$_POST['state_name']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['city_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['city_name'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."City = '".$_POST['city_name']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['start_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['start_date'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LastContactDate >='".$_POST['start_date']."'";
        }

        if(isset($_POST['end_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['end_date'])) > 0){
            $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."NextContactDate <= '".$_POST['end_date']."'";
        }

        $selectSQL .= " ORDER BY FirstName ASC, LastName ASC, Lead_Id ASC";

        $result_array = array();

        $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                array_push($result_array, $row);

            }

        }

        // print_r($result_array);

        echo json_encode($result_array);

        // $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info as M, tbl_campaign_info as C";

        $conn->close();

?>
```

File `loadtable.js`

```
// This is script to load table based on filter section

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Campaign Submit Info
    $('[name="search_submit"]').click(function(e) {

        $('#load-csv-file-button').attr('style','display:none;');
        $("#filterRecords").attr('style','display:block;');
        $('#add_lead_info').attr('style','display:none;');

        e.preventDefault();

        // GET the admin and user id value
        var adminvalue = $('#filterformpost').find('[name="adminvalue"]').val();
        var useridvalue = $('#filterformpost').find('[name="useridvalue"]').val();

        var lead_owner = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_owner_select option:selected').val();
        var lead_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_status_select option:selected').val();

        var company_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#company_name_select option:selected').val();
        var tech_area = $('#filterformpost').find('#tech_area_select option:selected').val();
        var firm_size = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_size_select option:selected').val();
        var firm_type = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_type_select option:selected').val();
        var country_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#country_name_select option:selected').val();

        var city_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#city_name_select option:selected').val();

        var state_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#state_name_select option:selected').val();
        var start_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#start_date_search').val();
        var end_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#end_date_search').val(); 

        // console.log('adminvalue: '+adminvalue)
        // console.log('useridvalue: '+useridvalue)
        // console.log('lead_owner: '+lead_owner)

        // console.log('country_name: '+country_name)
        // console.log('State: '+state_name)

        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "./server/search.php",
              data: {
                  "lead_owner": lead_owner,
                  "lead_status": lead_status,                
                  "company_name": company_name,
                  "tech_area": tech_area,
                  "firm_size": firm_size,
                  "firm_type": firm_type,
                  "country_name": country_name,
                  "city_name": city_name,
                  "state_name": state_name,
                  "start_date": start_date,
                  "end_date": end_date
              },
              beforeSend: function() {

                  $('.search_lead_filter_message_box').html(
                      '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
                  );
              },
              success:function(data){   

                  // console.log(data)

                  console.log("Data Length: "+data.length)

                  console.log(data)

                  if(data.length == 0){

                     $('.search_lead_filter_message_box').html('');
                     $("#filterRecords").html('No results fetched');

                  }

                  var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                  // console.log(result)       

                  //###########################################
                  // Pagination code start
                  //###########################################

                  $('.search_lead_filter_message_box').html('');

                  $("#filterRecords").empty();


                  //###########################################
                  // Pagination code end
                  //###########################################

                  $("#pagination").attr('style', 'display:block;');   

                  $("#number_of_rows").attr('style','display:block;');
                  $('#button-prev-next').attr('style','display:block;');                                

                  paginate_json_data(result, adminvalue, useridvalue)

              }           

          });         

    });    

});

function paginate_json_data(userDetails, adminvalue, useridvalue) {

    adminvalue = adminvalue
    useridvalue = useridvalue
    userDetails = userDetails

    var table = '';
    table = $("<table></table>");    

    $('#pagination').html('<div id="nav-numbers" class="col nav"></div>'); 

    $('#number_of_rows').html('');
    $('#number_of_rows').html('<p1>Total number of leads fetched: ' + userDetails.length + '</p1>');

    $('#button-prev-next').html('<button class="col PreviousButton" id="PreValue"><i class="ion-skip-backward"></i> Previous</button><button class="col NextButton" id="nextValue">Next <i class="ion-skip-forward"></i></button>');

    var max_size = userDetails.length;
    var sta = 0;
    var elements_per_page = 10;
    var limit = elements_per_page;

    if(max_size<10){

      // #####################################
      // NUMBER OF ROWS A < 10 START START
      // #####################################

      table.append('<thead><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Website</th><th>Designation</th><th>Email</th><th style="width: 150px;">Phone</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Country</th><th>Lead Status</th></thead>');

      table.append('<tbody id="myTable"></tbody>');

      goFun_Modified(sta, max_size);

      function goFun_Modified(sta, limit) {            

        for (var i = sta; i < limit; i++) {         

           var tab = '<tr><td>' + (i+1) + "\n" + '</td><td>' + "<a target='_blank' href=./lead/index.php?lead_id=" + userDetails[i].Lead_Id + " </a>" + userDetails[i].FirstName + ' ' + userDetails[i].LastName + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Company + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Website + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Designation + "\n" + '</td><td>' + "<a href=mailto:" + userDetails[i].Email + ">" + userDetails[i].Email + "</a>" + "\n" + '</td><td style="width: 150px;" >' + userDetails[i].Phone + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].City + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].State + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Country + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].LeadStatus + "\n" + '</td></tr>';

           console.log(tab)               

          $('#myTable').append(tab)

        }
      } // Function ended      

      $("#filterRecords").html(table);

      $('#nextValue').click(function() { 

          // checks if it's the last page
          if (currentPage < maxPage) {
            currentPage++;
            $pagingBtn.removeClass('active');
            $pagingBtn.eq(currentPage).addClass('active')
          } else {
            alert("End of page");
          }                     

      });

      $('#PreValue').click(function() {  

        // checks if it's the first page
        if (currentPage > 0) {
          currentPage--;
          $pagingBtn.removeClass('active');
          $pagingBtn.eq(currentPage).addClass('active')
        } else {
          alert("Start of page")
        }     

      });

      var number = Math.round(userDetails.length / elements_per_page);

      for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {

        $('.nav').append('<button class="nav-numbers btn" id=' + i + '>' + (i+1) + '</button>');

      }

      $('.nav button').click(function() {

        var start = $(this).text()-1;

        // $(this).css({"background-color": "#e67e22", "color": "#ffffff"});

        $('#myTable').empty();

        limit = 10 * (parseInt(start) + 1) > max_size ? max_size : 10 * (parseInt(start) + 1)

        goFun_Modified(start * 10, limit);

        let $self = $(this);
        // gets index of button relative to it's siblings
        // https://api.jquery.com/index/
        currentPage = $self.index();
        $pagingBtn.removeClass('active');
        $self.addClass('active');

      });

      // saves all the paging buttons for reusing, instead of calling $() every time
      let $pagingBtn = $('#nav-numbers .btn');
      let maxPage = $pagingBtn.length - 1;
      let currentPage = 0;

      $('.nav button')[0].click()

      // #####################################
      // NUMBER OF ROWS A < 10 END
      // #####################################

    }else{

        // #####################################
        // NUMBER OF ROWS A > 10 START
        // #####################################  

        table.append('<thead><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Website</th><th>Designation</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Country</th><th>Lead Status</th></thead>');

        table.append('<tbody id="myTable"></tbody>');

        goFun(sta, limit);

        function goFun(sta, limit) {

          for (var i = sta; i < limit; i++) {           

           var tab = '<tr><td>' + (i+1) + "\n" + '</td><td>' + "<a target='_blank' href=./lead/index.php?lead_id=" + userDetails[i].Lead_Id + " </a>" + userDetails[i].FirstName + ' ' + userDetails[i].LastName + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Company + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Website + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Designation + "\n" + '</td><td>' + "<a href=mailto:" + userDetails[i].Email + ">" + userDetails[i].Email + "</a>" + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Phone + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].City + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].State + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].Country + "\n" + '</td><td>' + userDetails[i].LeadStatus + "\n" + '</td></tr>';

            $('#myTable').append(tab)

          }

          $("#filterRecords").html(table);

        }// FUNCTION ENDED

        $('#nextValue').click(function() {

          var next = limit;
          if (max_size >= next) {

            def = limit + elements_per_page;

            limit = def

            $('#myTable').empty();

            if (limit > max_size) {

              def = max_size;

            }

            goFun(next, def);

          }   

          // checks if it's the last page
          if (currentPage < maxPage) {
            currentPage++;
            $pagingBtn.removeClass('active');
            $pagingBtn.eq(currentPage).addClass('active')
          } else {
            alert("End of page");
          }

        });

        $('#PreValue').click(function() {

          var pre = limit - (2 * elements_per_page);
          if (pre >= 0) {

            limit = limit - elements_per_page;
            $('#myTable').empty();
            goFun(pre, limit);

          }

          // checks if it's the first page
          if (currentPage > 0) {
            currentPage--;
            $pagingBtn.removeClass('active');
            $pagingBtn.eq(currentPage).addClass('active')
          } else {
            alert("Start of page")
          }

        });

        var number = Math.round(userDetails.length / elements_per_page);

        for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {

          $('.nav').append('<button class="nav-numbers btn" id=' + i + '>' + (i+1) + '</button>');

           if(i == number){

          }          

        }       

        $('.nav button').click(function() {

          var start = $(this).text()-1;

          $('#myTable').empty();

          limit = 10 * (parseInt(start) + 1) > max_size ? max_size : 10 * (parseInt(start) + 1)

          goFun(start * 10, limit);

          let $self = $(this);
          // gets index of button relative to it's siblings
          // https://api.jquery.com/index/
          currentPage = $self.index();
          $pagingBtn.removeClass('active');
          $self.addClass('active');

        });

        // saves all the paging buttons for reusing, instead of calling $() every time
        let $pagingBtn = $('#nav-numbers .btn');
        let maxPage = $pagingBtn.length - 1;
        let currentPage = 0;

        $('.nav button')[0].click()

        // #####################################
        // NUMBER OF ROWS A > 10 END
        // ##################################### 

      }

  }
```

**Updated:**

[image]

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047217/ajax-syntax-error-unexpected-token-a-in-json-at-position-0) post ?

Comment: here i am getting all rows correctly as you can see in PHP array in console, only the thing is json_encode which is not working properly either due to some values in array which has comma or some value problem which obstructing in encoding JSON using the PHP array

Answer (score 0):

Try add content-type specs to http header:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

and set UNICODE feature in json_encode:

```
echo json_encode($result_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: where to use `header("Content-Type: application/json");` is in server PHP file?

Comment: Before echo command. Generaly before first php script output.

Comment: Check space or EOL before `<?php` tag. Character `<` must be first character in file.

Comment: hi i am getting the error, you can see in updated question.

Comment: When `console.log(data)` view JS object structure, then `data` variable is'nt `string` but js object. `$.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse` require string as parameter.

Comment: If you add `$.ajax` parameter `dataType: "JSON"` then `data` parameter in `success` will be `JS Object`.

Comment: Set JS Breakpoint on line `console.log("Data Length: "+data.length)` and type in console: `type of data`